# R combining two rows into one using person.id

Tags: r, rows

I have the following problem with R in combining more rows into one using person.id.
I have a dataset like this one:

```
person.id   Treatment   easy_comp   medium_comp   age   female
1_1          Happy         NA            NA        NA     NA
1_1          Happy         5             2         NA     NA
1_1          Happy         NA            NA        NA     NA
1_1          Happy         NA            NA        29     1
1_2          Happy         NA            NA        NA     NA
1_2          Happy         3             5         NA     NA
1_2          Happy         NA            NA        NA     NA
1_2          Happy         NA            NA        25     0
1_3
...
```

I want to obtain something like:

```
person.id   Treatment   easy_comp   medium_comp   age   female
1_1          Happy         5             2         29     1
1_2          Happy         3             5         25     0
1_3
...
```

If I run:

```
dt_remain1=dt_remain %>%
  group_by(person.id) %>%
  fill(easy_comp,medium_comp,female,age,.direction="up") %>%
  distinct
```

I obtain something like:

```
person.id   Treatment   easy_comp   medium_comp   age   female
1_1          Happy         5             2         29     1
1_1          Happy         NA            NA        29     1
1_2          Happy         3             5         25     0
1_2          Happy         NA            NA        25     0
1_3
...
```

What is the problem with my codes?
Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: After using `fill` do you expect the the final result to have no `NA` values in any of the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ways of solving this one.

If you want to get rid of any rows with any `NA` values, we can add `na.omit` to your chain:

```
dd %>%
    group_by(person.id) %>%
    fill(easy_comp,medium_comp,female,age,.direction="up") %>%
    na.omit() %>% 
    distinct()
```

Otherwise, we could say `direction = "updown"` to fill in both directions:

```
dd %>%
    group_by(person.id) %>%
    fill(easy_comp,medium_comp,female,age,.direction="updown")  %>%
    distinct()
```

Either approach results in the same:

```
#   person.id Treatment easy_comp medium_comp   age female
#   <chr>     <chr>         <int>       <int> <int>  <int>
# 1 1_1       Happy             5           2    29      1
# 2 1_2       Happy             3           5    25      0
```